# Unable to extract information with python requests

Tags: html, web-scraping, dom, python-requests

I'm a beginner in webscraping and I'm working on a project to extract contact information for NBA teams on their official websites. I'm using requests.get to extract the html code for the website, but for some reason the html that I download is very different than the html I see then I hit inspect, and I can't seem to find the information that I need. The sample website is https://www.nba.com/lakers/contact?ls=nav_extended_fans
I suspect it has something to do with javascript, but I can't seem to find a solution online. Is there anyway I can get what I see in "inspect"? (I'm using chrome btw)

Comment: Use a browser automation toolset, like Selenium or Puppeteer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That content comes from another request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://orchestration-layer-lalakers.vercel.app/HiKPY7hhv7UtFI4Cpr542'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
contact = soup.find('div', {'class':re.compile("^TextModule--body")}).get_text(separator="\n")

print(contact)
```

**Output:**

```
Phone:
(310) 426-6000
Crypto.com Arena:
1111 S. Figueroa St.
Los Angeles, CA 90015
UCLA Health Training Center:
2275 E. Mariposa Ave.
El Segundo, CA 90245
```